# HTML validator issues

Tags: html, utf-8

How do I fix the encoding of my webpage. The webpage can be found at 
[cis.csuohio.edu/~daloucks/test.html](http://cis.csuohio.edu/~daloucks/test.html)
I'm doing this for a class and we are required to eliminate all the warnings.  Once I add the meta tag I get stray tag errors.  I was told to change the encoding in my editor to `UTF-8` (I'm using notepad++), this added more errors.  I used plain notepad and this also didn't solve the problem.

i.imgur.com/N6jjOfM.png These are the errors I am getting, after I changed test to text. I'm using a validator at https://validator.w3.org and that is giving me the warnings for the encoding of the document.

Comment: I dont see any encoding errors in that URL, am I missing something ?

Comment: where are the warnings???

Comment: the only warning i see it in your 'h2' tag style `h1 {
  color: orange;
  test-align: center;
}`  , use `text-align` not  test-align

Comment: The `<style>` are outside of `<head>`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/N6jjOfM.png   These are the errors I am getting, after I changed test to text. I'm using a validator at https://validator.w3.org/ and that is giving me the warnings for the encoding of the document.

Comment: Your web server seems to be setting an HTTP header denoting the site to be encoded in Latin-1, overriding your internal `<meta>` element (pretty much just rephrasing what the validator is already telling you). You need to configure the web server to set the right encoding HTTP header; you may have to talk to your server admins for this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your document to look like this and then revalidate

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title> Test </title>
 <style>
     body{
              background-color: #d0e4fe;
        }

    h1{
        color: orange;
        text-align: center;
      }

    p{
         font-family: "Times New Roman";
         font-size: 20px;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed those, thanks. I added the link to the validator that is giving me the issues with the encoding of the document.

Comment: please place the `<style>` tag inside `<head>` tag and try to remove `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: My professor required the meta tag to be there.  He's taking points off, a lot of points, since I can't get the document to encode in UTF-8 it's encoding itself in iso-8859-1.  Should the title tag be in between the head tags in the style tags as well?

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcis.csuohio.edu%2F~daloucks%2Ftest.html;ss=1 This is the last step.  The encoding is in iso-8859-1 still.

Comment: @Dave I edited my answer, try to change your html to be like that

Comment: I copied an pasted your code into my test.html and I get the error Internal encoding declaration UTF-8 disagrees with the actual encoding of the document (windows-1252).

Comment: Open your file in notepad, then save as > Encoding : UTF-8 (next to the save button).

Comment: When I do that this happens in the validator. https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcis.csuohio.edu%2F~daloucks%2Ftest.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Comment: I think the issue is lying else where.  That works, but when I use it and save it as UTF-8 in Notepad I get loads of errors in the validator.

Comment: please copy and paste again, make sure there is nothing infront of `<!DOCTYPE html>` not even a space

Comment: Copied and pasted again.  The validator is now only saying UTF-8 doesn't match up with the  actual encoding windows-1252. I'm using Bitvise to send the files over to another computer on campus.  Could that be the issue here? (edit)  I just checked the encoding on that and it is UTF-8.